# Jython: Check for a Java object type

Tags: java, python, jython

I have *two* Java classes `Foo` and `FooBar` under some package. Both of these classes implement interface FooIFC. I want to find if the instance is of type `Foo` or `FooBar` from a *Jython* script.

I have a static `getinstance()` in one of the base class(implementors) of IFC

```
from package import FooIFC
from package import Foo

if FooIFC.getinstance() instanceof Foo:
    print "Foo"
else:
     print "FooBar"
```

I also tried `isintance(FooIFC.getinstance(), Foo)` as well . Which give an error name not found.

`instanceof` give expecting colon error.

How do I find the object type from a python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `instanceof` operator in python, instead there is the `isinstance` (that is isin**s**tance) builtin function. Thus:

```
from package import FooIFC
from package import Foo

if isinstance(FooIFC.getinstance(), Foo):
    print "Foo"
else:
    print "FooBar"
```

Comment: When I tried is instance(FooIFC.getinstance(), Foo)  i get a method not found error

Answer (score 0):

In `Jython`, you can also try.

```python
from package import FooIFC
from package import Foo

if FooIFC.getClass().getSimpleName() == 'Foo':
    print "Foo"
else:
    print "FooBar"
```

*Sample Code:*

```python
import java.util.ArrayList as ArrayList

arr = ArrayList()
arr.add(10)
arr.add(20)
print arr
print "Name:", arr.getClass().getName()
print "Simple Name:", arr.getClass().getSimpleName()

if arr.getClass().getName() == 'java.util.ArrayList':
    print "This is an ArrayList"

if arr.getClass().getSimpleName() == 'ArrayList':
    print "This is an ArrayList"
```

*Output:*

```
> jython check_type.py
[10, 20]
Name: java.util.ArrayList
Simple Name: ArrayList
This is an ArrayList
This is an ArrayList
```